# Sentry 2 with ldap

Tags: php, laravel, ldap, cartalyst-sentry

I am new at Laravel 4 and I am moving my projects CodeIgniter to Laravel. I thought to use Cartalyst Sentry 2 for user authentication and authorization. It's working with MySQL, it's ok but I wanna auth users over LDAP. We are using "single sign on" for our all projects.

Does Sentry accept custom login function? Or, how can I make this? Can you give me an idea?

Answer (score 3):

I checked but couldn't find anything about this. Then I writed my code and add to sentry library. I forked on github and share my code. Please write me on github if you get any issue when using library with ldap.

Github link : https://github.com/anndro/SentryLdap

Thanks